# I have a acer laptop that is auto shutting down on me while gaming, its not overheating how can I stop it?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, shutdown, cooling, gaming

I have opened my laptop up, cleaned it, added new thermal paste, checked the fans to see if they are working, and I have downloaded the Core CPU program to monitor the temp.  sometimes I can game all day long and sometimes it shuts down every 10 minutes while gaming. If I don't game it doesn't shut down at all.  idle temp is 112 F. gaming temp is 145 F... auto shut off temp is 185 F but its been shutting off at 133 F randomly.  its not even warm to the touch when it shuts off. I have Malwarebites program to check for viruses and they say there is none.  only conclusion I can come up with is hardware failure and after reading many post online about Acer brand it seems to support this... is there anything I can do other than buy another computer?

Comment: First, a note, we almost all use Celcius for temperature measuring, so you will get better understanding from the community if you do so as well. As for your issue, if it isn't thermal, it is likely an issue of insufficient power. Thats just a hunch, based on prior experience though; it could be a mainboard issue, or a problem in the power converter. or even an out of control peripheral. do you have any usb devices drawing power?

Comment: I have just 1 USB device and that's my keyboard. my mouse is wireless and works on a battery.

Comment: oh and its running at 57 degrees Celsius before it shuts off. only turning off when in the middle of a game, it can run all day doing browsing and other functions with no problems.

Comment: Does it shutdown or reboot? If it's a reboot, recent windows are configured by default to restart immediately after a Blue Screen of Death (BSOD), so it's possible to look forward for the culprit (which windows version?). If it's a real shutdown, it's probably a hardware/power issue (remove battery, try another power converter)

Comment: no its a complete shut down, it gives a few lag pauses then just turns off. it doesn't do the "waiting for programs to shut down" or anything it just powers down completely like the power button is pressed but without doing windows shut down. I took out the battery and tried a different power converter... neither worked.

Comment: Your system's BIOS is detecting some type of failure and being shut down to prevent damage. It may not be overheating, but something is going. You've seemed to have tested the power end of it, so it may be a failing component (probably GPU related)? What is the model of your laptop? Have you also checked Event Viewer or your dump file location `C:\Windows\Minidump` to make sure it's not getting a BSOD and failing to display it?

Comment: My laptop is an acer aspire 7551G .  I can't check the minidump files they tell me access is denied when I try and open them... I have 2 there.

Comment: You can use this tool: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html to inspect the minidump

Comment: here is the windump for the latest date of 10/31
http://i66.tinypic.com/d5g.png

Comment: so, this dump is related to your atheros network card (athrx.sys), try to update (or downgrade) your drivers, or to completely disable this card

Comment: I already have... i got the newest drivers on November 4th but its not a crashing issue that I have, the computer is doing a shut down not a crash. and it has been doing it randomly for the past few months, only lately has it gotten worse... always during a game.  It never shuts down outside of gaming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to loose screws on the reverse of the case. There is a safety feature which kills power on Acer laptops when the hardware detects the case is open (and power is on). By tightening the screws on the reverse of the laptop (hard!), the problem magically goes away. Since these screws are self-loosing, this may need to be repeated every few years.

The problem (with resolution) is [described in great detail here](https://superuser.com/questions/1008809/laptop-shuts-down-suddenly-when-running-on-battery).